# How come compiling my .tex file with my alias is lagging?

Tags: bash, latex, alias

I have written an alias in `~/.bashrc` to compile my tex files into pdfs. I am sure that `~/.bashrc` is sourced.

```
alias p='rm -f *.pdf *.log *.aux;pdflatex *.tex;open *.pdf'
```

However, after I edit my .tex file in XCode, save, and run the command `p` in my terminal, the pdf that opens is a previous version, not the latest version. The pdf matching the latest version of my tex file surfaces after I run `p` several times.

What is causing the lag? My Mac Air runs Lion.

Comment: Update: `pdflatex` is working at compiling the right version of my tex. However, the `open` command seems to be opening an older version of my pdf. Why?

Comment: Are you sure that open really opens the file again? It may just display the already opened pdf from the previous run again. And did you look at the timestamps of your .tex and .pdf files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- This question better asked at the TeX.SE site.
- .tex files need to be compiled multiple times, not just once. Run `pdflatex *.tex` 3x and then open, and it should work
- There are much much better LaTeX editors than XCode.
- The `latexmk` script is, in my opinion, the best .tex compiler. It handles compiling the file as many times as necessary. `rubber` is another LaTeX compiler.

Comment: Thank you. 1) That makes sense, sorry. 2) Why does pdflatex require multiple compilations? That sounds redundant. 3) Thanks, I'll look around. 4) I'll check out latexmk.

Comment: `pdflatex` doesn't require multiple compilations. Your .tex file requires multiple compilations. Reasons might be explained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19638/is-pdflatex-a-one-pass-compiler and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35832/what-are-the-situations-where-you-have-to-compile-a-document-more-than-once and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30674/document-requiring-infinitely-many-compiler-passes It isn't redundant, it is the architecture of (La)TeX. It needs one pass to find, for ex, references, and another to build the ToC, etc.

Comment: Also, perhaps your alias is the issue. You use `pdflatex *.tex`. Do you have multiple .tex files in this folder? *.tex will, I think, default to alphabetical (complicated by UTF-8, i8n, upper/lowercase, etc.), which might make it compile things in the wrong order if you are compiling multiple things.